# accuratelly place a node above and left of another node

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I am trying to draw a box which is defined as a node, next to another node.

My code is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  pipe/.style = {
    draw,
    %top color=gray!60, 
    %bottom color=gray!20, 
    minimum width=4cm, 
    minimum height=.1cm, 
    anchor=east,
  },
  source/.style = {
    draw,
    %top color=gray!60, 
    %bottom color=gray!20, 
    minimum width=.8cm, 
    minimum height=.4cm, 
    %anchor=east,
  }
  }

\begin{document}
 \definecolor{tank}{RGB}{98,190,177}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  %tank
  \coordinate (tank) at (0,0);
  \draw[tank, fill=tank] (-2,0.5)--(-0.5,1)--(0.5,1)--(2,0.5)--(2,-0.5)--(0.5,-1)--(-0.5,-1)--(-2,-0.5)--cycle;
  %pipes
  \coordinate (pipe1) at (-2,0);
  \node[pipe] at (pipe1) (pipe1) {};%left pipe
  \coordinate (pipe2) at (2,0);
  \node[pipe,anchor=west] at (pipe2) (pipe2) {};%right pipe
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe2,rotate=-90] (pipe3) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-160] (R3) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-130] (R2) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-110] (R1) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-80] (L1) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-50] (L2) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-20] (L3) {};
  \node[pipe, left=0mm of pipe1,rotate=-30] (sputter) {};
  \node[pipe, left=0mm of pipe1,rotate=30] (duoplasmatron) {};
  %experimental chamber
  \node[circle,fill=red,right=-1.5mm of L1] {};
  %sources  
  \node[source, above left=3mm of sputter,rotate=45] (spusource) {BOX};
  %\node[source, above=3mm of sputter, left=3mm of sputter,rotate=45] (spusource) {BOX};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and my output is

[image]

I am trying to place the `BOX` just left of the sputter. I tried using `above=3mm of sputter, left=3,, of sputter` but it seems that only the last positioning command is parsed. How can I do that?

Comment: Try `above left = ycm and xmm of sputter`. y for vertical above/below y distance and x for left /right x distance.

Comment: @Jesse : This did fix it! The thing is that I have to play around a lot with the positions. Is there a way to "automatically" place the box right next to the sputter?

Comment: What do you mean by automatic placement? At least one needs to provide `above left= ymm and xmm of an object`.

Comment: If `above left` and `sputter` are fixed, then values y and x must be provided by the code.

Comment: I mean the following:`sputter` is the coordinate on the center of the tube. Is there a way to define the left and right side of the tube without having to manually adjust `x` and `y`?

Comment: After some tests, I found this regularity: Please try   `\node[source, left=0mm (or any value) of sputter,rotate=60,anchor=south] (spusource) {BOX1};` the rotate=60 is related to -30 of sputter by 60-(-30)=90. Hope this help. Depending on the density of the tubes, you many need to try more. According to your code there are only two tubes, probably will work.

Comment: This really works. The user has to play around with `anchor`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** This seems to be what the OP really wants.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  pipe/.style = {
    draw,    %top color=gray!60, 
    %bottom color=gray!20, 
    minimum width=4cm, 
    minimum height=.1cm, 
    anchor=east,
  },
  source/.style = {
    draw, 
    %top color=gray!60, 
    %bottom color=gray!20, 
    minimum width=.8cm, 
    minimum height=.4cm, 
    %anchor=east,
  },

\begin{document}
 \definecolor{tank}{RGB}{98,190,177}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  %tank
  \coordinate (tank) at (0,0);
  \draw[tank, fill=tank] (-2,0.5)--(-0.5,1)--(0.5,1)--(2,0.5)--(2,-0.5)--(0.5,-1)--(-0.5,-1)--(-2,-0.5)--cycle;
  %pipes
  \coordinate (pipe1) at (-2,0);
  \node[pipe] at (pipe1) (pipe1) {};%left pipe
  \coordinate (pipe2) at (2,0);
  \node[pipe,anchor=west] at (pipe2) (pipe2) {};%right pipe
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe2,rotate=-90] (pipe3) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-160] (R3) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-130] (R2) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-110] (R1) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-80] (L1) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-50] (L2) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-20] (L3) {};
  \node[pipe, left=0mm of pipe1,rotate=-30] (sputter) {};
  \node[pipe, left=0mm of pipe1,rotate=30] (duoplasmatron) {};

%experimental chamber
\node[circle,fill=red,right=-1.5mm of L1] {};

\node[source, left=0mm  of sputter,rotate=60,anchor=south] (spusource) {BOX};
\node[source, rotate=120,left=0mm of duoplasmatron,anchor=south, ] (spusource1) {BOX};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After several discussions with the OP, `above left = ...` is manually tedious to play around with the positions, especially for coordinates (x,y) values. To avoid that, the OP wishes an automatic way to place the `box`.  After several attempts, this solution does not play with the `anchor` or `rotate`, as suggested in my second comment. All is needed is the left=xx mm of an object and with alignment too.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  pipe/.style = {
    draw,    %top color=gray!60, 
    %bottom color=gray!20, 
    minimum width=4cm, 
    minimum height=.1cm, rounded corners=3pt,
    anchor=east,
  },
  source/.style = {
    draw, 
    %top color=gray!60, 
    %bottom color=gray!20, 
    minimum width=.8cm, 
    minimum height=.4cm, 
    anchor=east,
  },

\begin{document}
 \definecolor{tank}{RGB}{98,190,177}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  %tank
  \coordinate (tank) at (0,0);
  \draw[tank, fill=tank] (-2,0.5)--(-0.5,1)--(0.5,1)--(2,0.5)--(2,-0.5)--(0.5,-1)--(-0.5,-1)--(-2,-0.5)--cycle;
  %pipes
  \coordinate (pipe1) at (-2,0);
  \node[pipe] at (pipe1) (pipe1) {};%left pipe
  \coordinate (pipe2) at (2,0);
  \node[pipe,anchor=west] at (pipe2) (pipe2) {};%right pipe
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe2,rotate=-90] (pipe3) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-160] (R3) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-130] (R2) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-110] (R1) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-80] (L1) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-50] (L2) {};
  \node[pipe, right=0mm of pipe3,rotate=-20] (L3) {};
  \node[pipe, left=0mm of pipe1,rotate=-30] (sputter) {};
  \node[pipe, left=0mm of pipe1,rotate=30] (duoplasmatron) {};

%experimental chamber
\node[circle,fill=red,right=-1.5mm of L1] {};

\node[source, left=2mm of sputter] (spusource) {BOX};

\node[source, left=2mm of duoplasmatron] (spusource1) {BOX};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```